# Css help - background images and margins

Tags: css, html

im trying to change the custom CSS of my page headers, but every time i try to add a top-margin to one of the nested divs, it moves the entire background image down.
Current code (abridged):

```
<header id="fancy-header" style="
       background-color: #ffffff; background-size: cover;   
       background-repeat: no-repeat; 
       background-image: url(http://thegsc.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/about-header.jpg); 
       background-position: center center; min-height: 150px">
    <div class="wf-wrap">
        <div class="wf-table" style="
             background:rgba(32,117,200, .6) !important; 
             margin-top:25px;">
           <div class="title">title</div><div class="breadcrumbs">breadcrumbs</div>
       </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Ideally, all Im trying to do is have a background image that spans the entire header (150px), and then a transparent-color overlay on the background text.
Using `margin-top:25px` because when i tried adding a vertical-align:middle to .wf-table, nothing happened.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is that your .wf-table element was not respecting #fancy-header as its parent. The trick is to add `float: left` and it'll behave in this case as you expect. Check it out here - https://jsfiddle.net/96hf0nqa/

Floats are a little tricky but super important for effective CSS. You can read a lot about them [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/). Good luck!

Comment: This is also possible but then you'll need a clearfix on the wrapper. Otherwise you can't really call it a `wf-wrap`.

Answer (score 1):

If your `<header>` is the main container to be full-screen then ideally you should be using a grid approach.

Not sure if you use a grid or not? In this case the `wf-wrap` is your grid-row:

```
.wf-wrap {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* box model fix */
    max-width: 94rem; /* 960px - gutter */
    padding: 0 1rem; /* grid gutter */
    margin: 0 auto; /* to center */
    height: 100%;
    position: relative; /* to init the absolute offset of it's children */
}
```

Then your `wf-table` should be positioned absolute to have full control:

```
.wf-table {
    position: absolute; /* to control top left right bottom */
    top: 2.5rem; /* default offset */
    z-index: 1 /* if overlap requires it */;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tive/4zrmbuqL/)**

---

Typically a grid-row is divided into columns. The position relative belongs on a column actually.

```
.column {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.g50 { max-width: 50%; width: 100%; }
```

So your HTML can be made a little bit more generic to gain control on the position of elements inside columns.

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column g50">
            <div class="wf-table"><!--content here--></div>
        </div>
        <div class="column g50"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tive/ydjbjrb6/)**

Additionally there is a way to vertically align a block element in CSS3:

```
.middle-y {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```